# Unsure as to cause of AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble with the error message AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' when running the three sections of code below in a jupyter notebook. Each paragraph is its own section in the jupyter notebook. I get the error when running the last two lines.

The goal of the code is to read information from the column identifiers in the excel document Step_One_CSV (which is currently saved as an Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)) and print it based on the index # x in print(identifiers[x]).

```
import cv2
import os
from pandas import *
import requests
import numpy as np
import json
import urllib
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

def read_image_data(Step_One):
    df = read_csv(Step_One)
    image_identifier_list = df.loc[df['identifier'] != "", 'identifier'].tolist()
    input_files = [x.strip() for x in image_identifier_list if x != ""]
    return input_files

identifiers = read_image_data ('Step_One_CSV.csv')
print(identifiers[1])
```

My immediate thought was that there was some kind of type discontinuity in the 'identifiers' column but after searching through that column I only found entries of the form 'error' or a string of characters such as '56dd883a4ff5c65c163e7dd86a0ba3e6a27b2e27892a30967507488562d345a7'. I am confused specifically as why the code is seeing either of these possibly as a float? Could it have to do with blank cells at the bottom of the excel sheet?

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please share some data and create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: So I am not really sure what happened but in the process of setting up the MRE the code seems to have started working. Not sure why. Thank you anyways for the response!